# Why can't an XBee coordinator send to a specific end device?

Tags: xbee

I'm experimenting with a pair of XBee S1 modules on XBee Explorer USB interfaces. I have them hooked up to XCTU and have them configured with 16-bit addresses, as follows:

Coordinator
[image: Coordinator XBee]

End device
[image: Other XBee]

So, coordinator MY address is 0xD0, the other module's MY address is 0xD1.

Using this configuration, I can easily send from the end device to the coordinator, using either transparent or API TX Request (16-bit addressing). This works fine. However, I cannot send from the Coordinator back to a specific end device (transmit always fails). For example, with the configuration exactly as shown, in AT mode, if I open console windows and type in the end device console, it shows up in the Coordinator console. But if I type in the Coordinator console... nothing.

I can get it to work if I send to DL=FFFF (PAN broadcast address) - but I don't want to have to broadcast to all devices. Right now there are only 2 devices so it wouldn't matter, but later there will be more and I need to address them individually.

So is this possible? If so, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: How is this working if the PAN ID is different on each device?  `0x6FBF` and `0x6FFF`?

Comment: That's actually a typo, but it would still work because the End Device has PAN reassignment enabled. Therefore, it will scan for available PANs and select the one with the strongest signal.

Comment: I'm not as familiar with the S1 modules as I am with S2/Zigbee and others.  I assume DH=0 signals 16-bit address mode.  Can you put the full 64-bit address in DH/DL and have it work?  Do you have the end device sleeping at all?  Is the end device configured with flow control such that it's waiting for you to assert RTS before sending its data out?